# How do i convert a string into a sting with " "

Tags: python

I have a string to which i want to add double quotation marks before and after it

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverseWords(self, s):

        a = []
        b = []
        a = s.split(" ")
        for i in reversed(a):
            b.append(i)


        string =  " ".join(b)
        return string
```

Expected = "blue is sky the"
actual = blue is sky the

Comment: You may need to use like " \" my string \" "

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using escape sequences.
backward slash followed by \ or " or ' is an escape sequence and can be used as follows -

```
print("\"hello world...\" \\ \'")
```

this would print -

```
"hello world..." \ '
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format as used in the snippet above .

```
a='hello world'
b = '"{}"'.format(a)
print b
```

prints hello world with double quotes .

Comment: "\"blue is sky the\""  This is what the output is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a double quote inside a string, you should use `/"`.

Example: `print("This is an \"example\" of a doublequote")`

This will give you: This is an "example" of a double quote

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to quote a bunch of variables is to iterate the list and convert your value to a string of your preferred format:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
b = ['"{}"'.format(x) for x in a]
```